# requestLocationUpdates error

Tags: android, gps, geolocation

please I have a problem with my code:

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private static final int REQUEST_LOCATION = 2;
    private Location myLocation;
    private final static int CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;
    public static final String TAG = MapsActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    protected LocationManager locationManager;
    protected LocationListener locationListener;
    Context context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .build();
        }

        mGoogleApiClient.connect();


        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    REQUEST_LOCATION);
        } else {
            // permission has been granted, continue as usual
            Location myLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        }

        if (myLocation == null) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Location services not enabled!");
        } else {
            handleNewLocation(myLocation);
        }


        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                .setInterval(3 * 1000)        // 3 seconds, in milliseconds
                .setFastestInterval(1 * 1000); // 1 second, in milliseconds


        locationManager = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        //Got aproblem with requestLocationUpdates !!!!
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 3, this);

    }


    private void handleNewLocation(Location location) {

        Log.d(TAG, location.toString());

        double currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
        double currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();

        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude);
        MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("I am here!");

        mMap.addMarker(options);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    }

    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
        //handleNewLocation(myLocation);
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

        Location mLastLocation;

        Log.i(TAG, "Location services connected.");

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        }
        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Location services suspended. Please reconnect.");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                // Start an Activity that tries to resolve the error
                connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "Location services connection failed with code " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        String str = "Latitude: "+location.getLatitude()+"Longitude: "+location.getLongitude();

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

In this part exactly:

> locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 3, this);

It says cannot resolve the method. I tried some "solutions" I found here, but none of them worked! 
Can you help me please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

dont pass **this** param;(remove implements LocationListener from that activity) instead do like this

```
LocationListener myLocationListener= new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            Log.d("dj","on location changed: "+location.getLatitude()+" & "+location.getLongitude());
            toastLocation(location);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

        }
    };
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 2000, 0, myLocationListener);


 private void toastLocation(final Location location){

    Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

    handler.post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(ServiceProvide.this.getApplicationContext(),"Location latitude: "+ location.getLatitude()
                    +"longitude: "+location.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: since ur fragmentActivity is implementing so many callbacks.. it might not take so; i guess this can help and also min_distance has to be 0 if the min_time need to work

Comment: Thank you DJphy,i don't get the error, but still the code doesn't work when i add :        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 1, locationListener);

Comment: dont use GPS_PROVIDER instead use LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER... and also make min distance 0 and give some min time as 2000 msec

Comment: but make sure the GPS is turned on and also write a toast like this:
@Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        Log.d("dj","on location changed: "+location.getLatitude()+" & "+location.getLongitude());
        toastLocation(location);
    }

      in on location changed

Comment: Hey DJphy, thx for responding. i wrote: 
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 2000, 0, locationListener);
but still the app doesn't work

Comment: yeah then what happened...its working for me.. make sure GPS is ON and Network is available and set the listener in oncreate... and im damn sure it will toast u the location ...if u have written the toast msgs on **onLocationChanged()**

Comment: Then when running the app, i got the error: "unfortunately, MyApp has stopped".

Comment: cooool ; stack trace please

Comment: Sorry i didn't understand you !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106598/discussion-between-teachmepls-and-djphy).